# validate phone number in AlertDialog -Android

Tags: android

This is my code where I have two edit text name and Phone number , can any one help me out validate phone number which should be applicable to my code below as I have come cross a lot of validation codes before.

```
public class PersonAddNumberDialog {
private AlertDialog dialog;

public PersonAddNumberDialog(final Context context, final ListView toUpdate) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    LinearLayout root = new LinearLayout(context);
    root.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    final EditText textName = new EditText(context);
    textName.setHint("Name");

    final EditText textNumber = new EditText(context);
    textNumber.setHint("Number");
    textNumber.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

    root.addView(textName);
    root.addView(textNumber);

    dialog = builder
                .setView(root)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String name = textName.getText().toString(), number = textNumber.getText().toString();
                        if (name != null && !name.equals(""))
                            if (number != null && !number.equals("")) {
                                Person p = new Person(number, name);
                                PersonManager.savePerson(p, context);
                               toUpdate.setAdapter(new PersonAdapter(context, PersonManager.getSavedPersons(context)));
                            }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                })
                .create();
}

public void show() {
    dialog.show();
}
```

}

Comment: Right now you are just checking if number is `null` or `""` . What is the validation that you try to implement? It's kind of unclear what your problem is

Comment: it should accept only phone number of 10 digits.

Comment: validating a phone number is not trivial task. there are a lot of phone number standards for each country. Do you want to validate any country's phone number?

Comment: `number.lenght()>=10`?

Comment: or 8 digits as number.

Comment: not specific to country but should accept 10 digits

Comment: @Meghana, check the answer i posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Meghana please try this..

```
  @Override
        public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog,int which){
            String name = textName.getText().toString();
            String number = textNumber.getText().toString();

            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                Log.e("Log", "enter name");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "enter name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            if (number.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                Log.e("Log", "enter number");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "enter number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (number.length() < 10) {
                Log.e("Log", "enter number is not valid");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "enter number is not valid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Person p = new Person(number, name);
                PersonManager.savePerson(p, context);
                toUpdate.setAdapter(new PersonAdapter(context, PersonManager.getSavedPersons(context)));

            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add <10 as a condition.

```
  private static boolean validatePhoneNumber(String phoneNo) {
            //validate phone numbers of format "1234567890"
            if (phoneNo.matches("\\d{10}")) return true;
            //validating phone number with -, . or spaces
            else if(phoneNo.matches("\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{3}[-\\.\\s]\\d{4}")) return true;
            //validating phone number with extension length from 3 to 5
            else if(phoneNo.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}\\s(x|(ext))\\d{3,5}")) return true;
            //validating phone number where area code is in braces ()
            else if(phoneNo.matches("\\(\\d{3}\\)-\\d{3}-\\d{4}")) return true;
            //return false if nothing matches the input
            else return false;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try something like this**:

```
if (!Patterns.PHONE.matcher(number).matches() || number.length() < 10){
           new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setTitle("Invalid Phone Number")
                            .setMessage("Please enter valid Phone Number.")
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, null)
                            .create().show();
        }else {
            // valid mobile number action 
        }
```